# Adsense for content not working

Tags: adsense

I have adsense for content set up for my site running on my blog.

It shows up below the post content on each single post (like this one):
http://engineercreativity.com/blog/learning-xhtml-and-css-day-12-of-30/

However, **instead** of this showing up:

Ads by Google   Ad1  Ad2  Ad3 ...

**THIS SHOWS UP**:

Ads by Google   View ads about: [textbox]  [button]

Does anyone please have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Amit

Comment: This might be a better fit on either the [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this programming related?

Anyway, you shouldn't modify AdSense's code provided by Google. If you are not getting expected results then either you modified Google's code or you are not selecting the correct options in your AdSense admin panel.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.